# Django - Unable to import _ssl module

Tags: python, django

i've seen all the topic about this subject and most are outdated or doesn't work for me.

I'm on `Linux version 4.4.0-21-generic (buildd@lgw01-21) (gcc version 5.3.1 20160413 (Ubuntu 5.3.1-14ubuntu2) )`

and i am using `python3.5`

I've already installed django (i can make some import from django)
And i didn't know why but when i try `python3 manage.py runserver`
The error traceback tell me that there is no module named `_ssl`
i've trying to resolve this problem all the weekend but cannot solve it.

```
File "/home/zouz/Desktop/django_project/smart-prospective-site/app/urls.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import views
File "/home/zouz/Desktop/django_project/smart-prospective-site/app/views.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .data import *
File "/home/zouz/Desktop/django_project/smart-prospective-site/app/data.py", line 4, in <module>
    import requests
File "/home/zouz/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 59, in <module>
    from .models import Request, Response, PreparedRequest
File "/home/zouz/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 19, in <module>
    from .packages.urllib3.fields import RequestField
File "/home/zouz/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
File "/home/zouz/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 31, in <module>
    from .connection import (
File "/home/zouz/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 45, in <module>
    from .util.ssl_ import (
File "/home/zouz/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .ssl_ import (
File "/home/zouz/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 12, in <module>
    import ssl
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 98, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
```

> ImportError: No module named '_ssl'

Thanks a lot for helping
and sorry for my not really good english

Comment: The _ssl module is a built-in module for python, it requires `openssl` installed on your system.

Comment: I've alreasy installed openssl

Comment: Try to recompile your python `cd Python3.5`  `./configure` `make && make install`

Comment: Working well thanks a lot !